# ajax got error on hosting the webpage

Tags: asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

My Website is working fine locally but got problem in making live.

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'asp:ScriptManager'.
I googled this problem and find solution as...

```
<pages>

<controls> <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

</controls> </pages>
```

I did same but got error again.....

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have uploaded ajaxtoolkit in Bin folder???? Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you haven't configure the right .net version.  Check with your webhosting company or control panel to see what .net version your site is using.  You can also try smarterasp.net, they let you set your own version via their control panel too.